# How do I implement return false; into JavaScript if/else

Tags: javascript, return-value

I'm trying to construct a nav bar that changes from height:'70px' to height:'50px' when the page is scrolled away from the top, and then changes back to height:'70px' whenever the page is scrolled back to the top.

To achieve this I've tried this code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_top > 0){
        $('nav').animate({
            height:'50px'
        });
    }else{
        $('nav').animate({
            height:'70px'
        });
    }
    });
});
```

What happens with this code is that the page loads correctly, and the first time I scroll down the height animates fine. However, whenever I scroll back to top it either won't change back to height:'70px', or (and this last part happens a lot when I try to animate additional values such as width or opacity) the entire nav bar looks to be flickering as if it were caught in a loop.

I spoke to a programmer yesterday who said it sounded like the page was re-firing .animate any time the pixel value of the nav bar changed while animating, creating an infinite loop. He suggested I implement a return false; condition to remedy this, but I'm unsure how exactly to implement it. Any help?

Suggestions on how do achieve this same effect in a different, more effective manner would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a lot simpler:

Have some CSS:

```css
nav {
    height:50px;
    transition:height 0.4s ease;
}
nav.scrolledFromTop {height:70px}
```

Now your jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("nav")[this.scrollTop > 0 ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("scrolledFromTop");
});
```

Done! That is the magic of CSS3 ;)

Comment: Should I be putting something in place of the "addClass" "remove Class"?

Comment: instead of `$(el)[cond ? "addClass" : "removeClass"](class)` you can do `$(el).toggleClass(class, cond)`

Comment: Hmm, this should work just fine, but it doesn't seem to be. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong on my end.

Comment: @LCW Please explain what doesn't seem to be working :)